# Notepad++ Folding Lines using Python

Tags: python, notepad++, fold

I'm using Notepad++ to write Python 2.7 code. I just want to create my own block indicator and fold the block so it is hidden. Something like:

```
#//begin
#//end
```

I'm going to use the comment # as the front character so as not to upset the code. All the questions and answers I've found on this topic are several years old back when Notepad++ seemed to allow this. Now the menus have changed and it doesn't seem possible to simply do this. There is the option to create a "User defined language" but I don't want to do this from scratch. I want to add this one feature to Python. Or, if it is simple enough, create my own language using Python defaults as a starting point and adding this one feature. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: I wouldn't use notepad++ for Python.

Comment: It's on my work machine. My options are limited. I picked Notepad++ because it has a portable version that doesn't require installation (admin privileges).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a user defined language using Notepad++ to just add folding can be done as follows:

1. Click on `Language > Define your language`
2. Click on `Create New...` and enter a name for it e.g. `Twegner`
3. In the section on the right add your `#//begin` and `#//end` styles for `Open` and `Close`.
4. Close the dialog and create a file using your styles.
5. Select `Language > Twegner` (which should now be shown at the bottom of the menu).

For example:

[image: Notepadd++ user defined language screenshot]

This would then work as follows:

[image: Folding example]

Comment: I've tried this, but then I lose all Python formatting as a result. I wish to keep the Python formatting and add this single feature. Can I create a user defined language and use Python as the base default?

Comment: I think you might be out of luck based on this question - [Customizing syntax highlighting in Notepad++](https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/325ffdf9/). It looks like it might be built into Scintilla.